# Which functions are spherical derivatives?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, spheres

Let us define the differential operator
$$
Z=x_1 \partial_{x_2} - x_2 \partial_{x_1}, $$
where $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ are the standard Cartesian coordinates on $\mathbb R^3$. I would like to characterize the functions $h\in C^\infty(\mathbb S^{2})$ such that
$$\tag{1}
h=Zf, \qquad \text{for some }f\in C^\infty(\mathbb S^{2}).$$

The operator $Z$ is one of the generators of the rotation group $SO(3)$, in the sense that
$$\tag{2}
Zf(x)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac1\epsilon \big( f(R_\epsilon x)-f(x)\big), $$
where $R_\epsilon$ is the matrix
$$
R_\epsilon=\begin{bmatrix} 
\cos \epsilon & -\sin \epsilon & 0  \\
\sin \epsilon & \cos \epsilon & 0   \\ 
0 & 0 & 1  
\end{bmatrix}.$$
The formula (2) implies that
$$\int_{\mathbb S^{2}} Zf(x)\, dS(x)=0, $$
where $dS$ denotes the standard Lebesgue measure on the sphere. Thus, a necessary condition for (1) to hold is that
$$\tag{3}
\int_{\mathbb S^{2}} h\, dS = 0.$$
Also, since $Z$ vanishes at $(0,0, \pm 1)$, another necessary condition is
$$
\tag{4} h(0,0,\pm 1)=0.$$
**Are these two last conditions also sufficient?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. A stronger condition is needed. Since the orbints of $Z$ are the circles on constant lattitude, $Zf$ must integrate to zero over each such circle. This can be seen by working in standard spherical coordinates $(\theta,\varphi):[0,2\pi)\times(0,\pi)\to S^2$. In these coordinates, $Z=\partial_\theta$, so we can apply the fundamential theorem of calculus along the lattitudes, obtaining
$$
f(\theta,\varphi)=f(0,\varphi)+\int_0^\theta Zf(\theta',\varphi)d\theta'
$$
Since $f(0,\varphi)=\lim_{\theta\to 2\pi^-}f(\theta,\varphi)$, we must have $\int_0^{2\pi} Zf(\theta',\varphi)d\theta'=0$. If you modify your set of conditions, you can check sufficiency by checking if the above expression gives a smooth function on $S^2$ for some choice of $f(0,\varphi)$.

Comment: This answer is excellent and it really put me on the right track. Thank you a lot. I am only slightly puzzled by the identity $Z=\sin \phi \partial_\theta.$ According to my computations it should be $Z=\partial_\theta$. Not that it matters, actually.

Comment: Right; this was a mistake on my part.